# Why to use scope resolution operator while calling C++ method from Objective-C method?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have an Obj-C class **`StuffCompareController.mm`** and its implementation looks like:

```
@implementation StuffCompareController

int compareThings(char* string1, char* string2)
{
    //Some C++ implementation
}

- (BOOL) compareStuff:(NSString *)string1 withImage:(NSString *) string2
{
    const char *path1 = [string1 UTF8String];
    const char *path2 = [string2 UTF8String];

    compareThings((char *) path1, (char *) path2); // This throws an error  "No matching call to callThings"

    compareThings(NULL, NULL); // But this does not throw any error. It builds fine with this

    return NO;
}

@end
```

The strange thing (to me) as I mentioned in the code comments is that why the first call throws an error and not the second call. Moreover when I modify the first call to :

```
::compareThings((char *) path1, (char *) path2);
```

This call works fine with no error. Why is that so? Enlighten me up.

**Update**:
This Obj-C method `compareStuff:` is not yet called anywhere. It is only declared in .h file

Comment: Is this your entire code? You don't have some other function called `compareStuff` somewhere nearby?

Comment: Nope. I am not yet calling this method anywhere. Its only declared in .h file. Thats it

Comment: Can you try moving the `compareThings` function out of the implementation?

Comment: OMG. It works without scope operator. But why passing NULL gives no error

Comment: Could it be because you're passing 2 `const` strings into a function which takes non-`const` strings? It probably doesn't matter with NULL. What happens if you change the method signature? (It should be `const` in the signature since a compare function shouldn't change the strings.)

Comment: @user1118321 But I am typecasting while passing in. AFAIK, it shouldn't matter. I also created 2 const char * and passed those but still the same error